# How to edit and print template text programmatically with specific format?

Tags: flutter, dart, text, printing

I am trying to create an application to get inputs from the user and display them in a specific text template with custom format then print it .
let's say that I have this template and I want to replace some words in it with user inputs , so the question here how can I display this template with this format , Does it make sense to use text widget to achieve this result ? , And how can I pass user input to this template .
[image: let's say I have this template (random)]
[image: get inputs from user]